# java TCP iterative servers

Tags: java, tcp, iteration

I need to Design and implement an iterative TCP server application listening on the port 1039 providing the following service.
The Server can access all ASCII files stored on its host machine. Client requests the service by sending a file path (string), server then reads the specified file character by character, assembles the characters to the blocks of 2048 characters each (or less for the last block when end of file is reached) and sends these 2k blocks of data to the client.

I had produced the following code. However i am stuck with how i can assembles the characters to the blocks of 2048 characters each (or less for the last block when end of file is reached) and sends these 2k blocks of data to the client.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class TcpIterative {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Socket clientSock = new Socket();
    ServerSocket servSock;
    int port = 1039;

    try{
        servSock = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true)
        clientSock = servSock.accept();

        BufferedInputStream inps = new BufferedInputStream(clientSock.getInputStream());
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inps);

        String req = "";
        int c= 0;
        while ((c = isr.read())!=13)
        {
            req = req + (char)c;
        }

        BufferedOutputStream outs = new BufferedOutputStream (clientSock.getOutputStream());
        OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(outs, "US-ASCII");
        osw.write(responseBuffer);
        osw.flush();

                inps.close(); 
        outs.close();
        clientSock.close();
    } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

}
}
```

Comment: So, your problems are 1. How make 2k packet 2. how to full fill the last packet when its size is less than 2K 3. how to send the packet after that?

Comment: yeah does are my problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read from the file into a buffer of desired size. Then when it's full or when there is no more data to read, it will be sent. Something like this:

```
int buffSize = 2048;
int off = 0;
char[] cbuf = new char[buffSize];
while(true){
    int read = isr.read(cbuf, off, buffSize - off);
    if(read == -1){
        if(off > 0){
            osw.write(cbuf, 0, off);  // Send nonfull buffer
            osw.flush();
        }
        break;
    }else if(off + read == buffSize){
        osw.write(cbuf, 0, buffSize); // Full buffer, send it all
        osw.flush();
        off = 0;
    }else{
        off += read;
    }
}
```

First we initiate a buffer with your required buffer size. Then we want to read into this buffer until its full. We use the off variable to tell how much we have already buffered. We can't be sure that the method reads as much as we wants it to read, that's why we use the read variable to get the number of read chars from the stream.

When read returns -1, we are at the end of the stream. In that case we want to write what's in our buffer, that is from the beginning of the buffer, to the off(how much we have read so far into the buffer).

If read > 0, we simply check if the buffer is full, if so we send it all. Otherwise we just continue reading until it is or until the end of the stream has been reached.

Comment: can you maybe please explain to me how is the read working exactly, and why did you use the off variable?

Comment: I edited the post to contain an explanation